# Can't Switch between tabs in bootstrap 5 nav tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-5, login-page

I am trying to create a log in page , in which there will be two tabs . One for Log in and another for Register.I want to display username, password in log in tab and name, last name, e-mail in register tab. I have wrote the code and I can see those two tabs but the problem is I can't switch between them if I kept class="nav-link active" for log in tab alone then it is only been displayed even though I can see and touch the register tab I it's not switching.The same Happens when I keep class="nav-link active" register tab alone the log in tab is not accessible.I hope I have explained it clearly please feel free to enlighten me.All kind of replies are welcomed.Thank you.
The HTML Code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#login-contents" id="login-tab">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" >
                <a class="nav-link" href="#register-contents" id="register-tab">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="login-contents" class="tab-pane active">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="ip-username" placeholder="Username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="ip-password"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="register-contents" class="tab-pane fade">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="ip-f-name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="ip-l-name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E-Mail :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail Id" id="ip-e-mail"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A OTP will be sent to your mail id for verification.</td>
                        <td><Button class="btn btn-success" id="register-btn">Register</Button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code works by just adding `data-bs-toggle="tab"` to each of your `a.nav-link`s

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#login-contents" id="login-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Log In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#register-contents" id="register-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="login-contents" class="tab-pane active">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username :</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="ip-username" placeholder="Username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password :</td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="ip-password"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="register-contents" class="tab-pane fade">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name :</td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="ip-f-name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name :</td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="ip-l-name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E-Mail :</td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Your E-Mail Id" id="ip-e-mail"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A OTP will be sent to your mail id for verification.</td>
          <td>
            <Button class="btn btn-success" id="register-btn">Register</Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah Bro It works only in bootstrap version 4.5.2 . As soon as I switch it up to bootstrap 5 it's not working.Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: No, it's working in the snippet with 5.1.0, I just double checked using 5.0.0 and it also works.

Comment: Are you using the bootstrap.js?

Comment: After 5 months I came across the same problem again. I am using bootstrap cdn link. Anyways thank you for double checking

Comment: @NamasivaayamL Did you ever add `data-bs-toggle="tab"` to your `.nav-link`s?

Comment: Yes I did but it didn't work but Now I have no idea why it works. Thanks man for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tabs component and markup as [shown in the Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#using-data-attributes)

There is nothing in your code that would trigger the Tabs.

Comment: yeah did it but no improvements still
`<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
<li class="nav-item" id="login-tab" role="presentation">
<button class="nav-link active" id="login-tab-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#login-contents" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="true">Log In</button></li>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="login-contents" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username :</td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="ip-login"></td>
</tr>`